# AKKA Http multipart form extract data and file

Tags: scala, multipartform-data, akka-http

Server receives multipart form which contains a file and a JSON object. What whould be the best way to extract file along with the metadata and additional JSON object from request ?
Right now I have following code:

```
    pathPrefix(""){
  post {
    extractRequestContext {
      requestCtx => {
        implicit val materializer = requestCtx.materializer
        implicit val executionContext = requestCtx.executionContext
        fileUpload("file") {
          case (metadata, byteSource) => {
                  byteSource.runWith(FileIO.toPath(Paths.get(metadata.fileName))).onComplete {
                    case Success(posts) =>  {
                      formFields('campaign){
                        campaign => {
                          println(campaign)
                          complete(ApiResponse("OK"))
                        }
                    }}}
                      complete(ApiResponse("OK"))
                  }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

The problem is that AKKA sends the response before the request is read completely. And I'm not sure how to complete the route from here:

```
byteSource.runWith(FileIO.toPath(Paths.get(metadata.fileName))) ...
```

This expression producec IOResult, how can I transform it into a server.Route ?

Comment: can you please specify exactly what you want? i got that  it's not working as you want but what you want that's not clear.

Comment: I added more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two separate questions in there:

### How to extract JSON and file?

For example, if you request is like this:

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost/" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "metadata={ "key": "value" }" -F "attachment=image.png;type=image/png"
```

You have JSON defined in the `metadata` field. This is how you do it

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
path("") {
  post {
    extractRequestContext { ctx =>
      implicit val materializer = ctx.materializer
      formField('metadata) { metadata =>
        fileUpload("attachment") {
          case (fileInfo, byteSource) =>
            ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Your JSON object is extracted as a string and you can serialize back to the JSON object.

### Complete the route with IOResult

The problem is actually with the Scala's `onComplete` since it returns a Unit.

You can do this:

```
fileUpload("attachment") {
  case (metadata, byteSource) =>
    onComplete(byteSource.runWith(FileIO.toPath(Paths.get(metadata.fileName)))) {
      case Success(value) => complete("OK")
      case Failure(exception) => complete("NOT OK")
    }
}
```

This onComplete is from the package `akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives`